# Cause for raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, subprocess

My code :

```
jarfile = "res/StringUtilsv102.jar"
#project = "5.1"
#apkName = "com.am.fl"  // added to show what ll b strin passed on to the function
def generate_idfile(project,apkName):
    cmd = "java -jar %s listStringIds  %s %s" %(jarfile, project ,apkName)
    arglist = shlex.split(cmd)
    outfile = 'output.txt'
    idfile = "idfile.txt"
    if(os.path.exists(idfile)):
        os.remove(idfile)
    process = subprocess.Popen(arglist, cwd=os.getcwdu())
    process.wait()
    os.rename(outfile, idfile)
```

O/p is throwing error as No such file or directory.
I have tried all the possible solutions to clear the error but helpless .

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/local/libraries/i18n/data_set/data_set.py", line 150, in init_logical_path
    genStringIdXml.generate_idfile(project, apkName)
  File "/home/local/ANT /i18n/data_set/genStringIdXml.py", line 27, in generate_idfile
    process = subprocess.Popen(arglist, cwd=os.getcwdu())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: plz show complete error output.

Comment: Do you get the error if `cmd = 'java -version'` and you drop `cwd=os.getcwdu()`?

Comment: Yes , I tried running removing cmd = 'java -version' and cwd=os.getcwdu() . It is still throwing the same error .

Answer (score 0):

You either need to start a process where java binary exists:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(arglist, cwd="/path/to/java/dir")
```

Or use `shell=True` to allow `PATH` environment variable to resolve a path for you.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(arglist, shell=True)
```